# react render is using old and new state values, instead of just the new value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

I am trying to create a clock,  where the user can select a location and the current time there is rendered on the screen. The code works fine for the first user button click. However, if they then select a different location, the hour state value should update to the new value. It does this, but react is rendering the old value to the screen too. The hour on the clock, therefore, flickers between the two different values. Can anyone explain why this is happening, and how I can only display the new hour value after the user clicks for a second time?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ButtonClick from './Components/UserInputs.js'

 //define global time difference matrix
 var timeDiffMat= [0, 6, 1, 2, -5];

class Clock extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
        //this.userInput = this.userInput.bind(this);
        this.adjustForLocation = this.adjustForLocation.bind(this);
        this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
        this.state = {CityfromChild: "", hours:0, minutes: 0, seconds: 0, 
test:''};
        //this.initialSetTime = this.initialSetTime.bind(this);
        this.setTime = this.setTime.bind(this);

    }


     adjustForLocation(citySelected, numberOfClicks) { 

        function getTimeDiff () {

            if (citySelected == "Local Time") return  timeDiffMat[0]

            if (citySelected =="Tokyo") return  timeDiffMat[1]

            if (citySelected =="Cape Town") return  timeDiffMat[2]

            if (citySelected =="Moscow")return  timeDiffMat[3]

            if (citySelected =="New York") return  timeDiffMat[4]

        }

        this.timeDiff = getTimeDiff(citySelected)

        this.tick(this.timeDiff)

    }


tick(timeDiff){

        setInterval(()=> this.setTime(timeDiff), 1000)

    }

    setTime(timeDiff){
        this.setState({
             seconds: new Date().getSeconds(), 
             minutes: new Date().getMinutes()
            });
        this.setState({hours: timeDiff + new Date().getHours() })
    }


    // unmount Clock Component and invalidate timer
     componentWillUnmount() {
            clearInterval(this.interval);
          }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="border"> 
                <h3> Choose a city {}</h3>
                    <div className="button-container">
                        <ul>

                            <li> <ButtonClick getTimeOnClick = 
{this.userInput} adjustHoursForCity = {this.adjustForLocation} 
buttonLabel= "Local Time"/> </li> 
                            <li> <ButtonClick getTimeOnClick = 
{this.userInput} adjustHoursForCity = {this.adjustForLocation} 
buttonLabel= "Cape Town"/> </li>
                            <li> <ButtonClick getTimeOnClick = 
{this.userInput} adjustHoursForCity = {this.adjustForLocation} 
buttonLabel= "Moscow"/> </li>
                            <li> <ButtonClick getTimeOnClick = 
{this.userInput} adjustHoursForCity = {this.adjustForLocation} 
buttonLabel= "New York"/> </li>
                            <li> <ButtonClick getTimeOnClick = 
{this.userInput} adjustHoursForCity = {this.adjustForLocation} 
buttonLabel= "Tokyo"/> </li>
                            <button>{this.state.CityfromChild}</button>
                            <button>{this.state.test}</button>
                        </ul>   
                    </div>
                    <div>{this.state.hours}:{this.state.minutes}: 
{this.state.seconds} </div> 

            </div> 

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you calling setState two times in a row and not include the hours in the first setState? Maybe this could already solve your problem

Comment: ive tried this also but i still get the same problem

Comment: well, ok, but you still shouldn't do that, i'll take another look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update the time you create a new `setInterval`, but you don't clear the old one. So you will have multiple `setInterval` each setting the time using a different `timeDiff`.

Try something like:

```
tick(timeDiff) {
    if (this.timer) {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    }
    this.timer = setInterval(() => this.setTime(timeDiff), 1000)
}
```

Comment: so are you saying it is running two instances of `setInterval` simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, the `tick` function creates a new one, so you will create one every time you click a button to set the timeDiff

Comment: @SeanBarker I added some code that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind `setTimeInterval` to your component like `this.mySetTimeInterval = setTimeInterval(() => {});`
And anywhere else you can stop the running interval doing:

```
clearInterval(this.mySetTimeInterval)
```

Comment: why exactly do i need to bind the interval to its component? is it just so i can call it to clear it later?

Comment: When the component will unmount, the interval will keep running in the background causing memory leak. If you bind it to the component, you can clear it in the `componentWillUnmount`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `this.interval` in your code as used in `componentWillUnmount`, in the function `tick`, I believe you wanted to store the result of setInterval invocation in a variable named interval. As @rebecca said, you should probably use

```
 setTime(timeDiff) {
    setState(/* To avoid race conditions */ function(){
       return { 
       seconds: new Date().getSeconds(),
       minutes: new Date().getMinutes(),
       hours: timeDiff + new Date().getHours() 
     })
  }

tick(timeDiff) {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.setTime(timeDiff), 1000)
  }
```

To avoid race conditions